# Should i import css into a next page?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, directory-structure, react-css-modules

I want to ask if css can and should be imported into next pages.
is the page structure below acceptable, or what is the standard practice

```
/pages
    /home
        index.js
        index.module.css
    /cart
        index.js
        index.module.css
```

am i to move all the elements of a page that require styling into the components folder

Comment: Can? Yes. Should is an opinion but keeping multiple copies of the same file in sync adds work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the styles in their own folder like this:

```
/pages
    /home
        index.js
    /cart
        index.js
/styles
    home.module.css
    cart.module.css
```

And then import with `import homeStyles from '../styles/home.module.css`.